# Get jars from mvnrepository.com directly from Eclipse (java project)?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there an en easy way to set up an existing java project in Eclipse to get the required jar-files from mvnrepository? Instead of going to mvnrepository.com and download them manually and later "add jar-file" in Eclipse?

I accidently tried Configure -> Convert to Maven project, hoping it would work. It converted the whole project into something that wouldn't even run. "Main class missing" and so on. It took just about the whole day restoring back the normal Java project.

Can this be done with Ivy?

Comment: Your first thought was correct - use Maven (or Gradle) to manage your dependencies.  So I think your question should really be "how do I configure a Maven (or Gradle) project?".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't want a Maven project. I want to be able to run my program with just hitting ctrl+f11 like a normal Java project but with automatic download of jars

Comment: @Baked Inhalf: That is exactly what a Maven project is (Gradle works, too). Let Maven do the dependency stuff and then execute it as before.

Comment: Also when you converted project to Maven you either need to restructure your source directories to Maven default structure or configure Maven pom file to use your existing. That why it does not running now. Then you will be able to run it both ways. Eclipse and Maven.

Comment: @robert ok I will give it another try. Read that Ivy could do that too from within eclipse so I might as well try that too.